# Functions in a namespace

Tags: c++, object, namespaces, structure

I want to have functions with the same name but using different namespace. I have declared a function in a namespace:

**GPS.cpp**

```
namespace NSpace_IMUandGPS
{
//Read GPS Data Set Raspberry Pi's Time and date
void ReadGPS(FD &Fd, bool &GPSready, bool &TimeConfigured, S_POS &POS, S_GPS&GPS, S_IMU &IMU, double &Velocity)
{
 ...
}
```

}

**GPS.h**

```
namespace NSpace_IMUandGPS
{
void ReadGPS(FD &Fd, bool &GPSready, bool &TimeConfigured, S_POS &POS, S_GPS    &GPS, S_IMU &IMU, double &Velocity);
}
```

**MAIN.cpp**

I want to use this function in main with structures that are not declared in NSpace_IMUandGPS namespace. So, how should I do this? If I declare the function in a namespace, Do all the variables have to be defined in the same namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to have things used in a particular namespace to be defined in that namespace.

Your `namespace NSpace_IMUandGPS` will be part of global nameless namespace. So, if `structs` which are used in function `ReadGPS` are not within any other namespace then you will find no problem accessing them inside the function `ReadGPS`.

You can call the function in `main` as follows:
`NSpace_IMUandGPS::ReadGPS(/*all the required parameters*/);`

In general, if `variables/functions` are not defined inside any `namespace` then they can be used by their name itself.

If `variables/functions` are defined inside some `namespace` then you need to specify the `namespace` when using them.

For example:

```
struct XYZ
{
    int c;
};
namespace ABC
{
     int a;
     struct PQR
     {
         int b;
     };
     Func_1(XYZ st1, PQR st2);
}

Func_2(XYZ st1, ABC::PQR st2);
```

`struct XYZ and Func_2` are part of global nameless `namespace`.
`int a and struct PQR` are part of `namespace ABC`.

Now if you see `Func_1` can access `struct XYZ` even though its not defined inside `namespace ABC`. This is because `namespace ABC` is itself part of global nameless `namespace`.

But if a function which is present in global nameless `namespace` such as `Func_2()` then inorder to use things inside `namespace ABC`, you need to specify the name of `namespace` like `ABC::PQR`.

Answer (score 1):

You can address a namespace using the :: operator. 
Syntax: `namespace::function();`

So in case you wannt to you, in example the std namespace use:
`std::merge();`
and if you want to use your code use:
`NSpace_IMUandGPS:ReadGPS();`